# How to download all package.json dependencies from Github

Tags: reactjs, github, npm

I need to install a React application, but due to firewall restrictions, I can only access to github.com;
I know it is possible to download a specific package directly from Github, example :

> npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli.git#v1.0.27

But is it possible to install all package.json dependencies using Github DNS ? And if yes what is the configuration ?

Comment: This might be useful https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/install-npm-packages-from-gitgithub

Comment: Yes I've seen this, but I would like to install all packages in one time ; thanks for the link btw

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install the react package from GitHub, you would replace the following line in your dependencies section:

```
"react": "^17.0.1"
```

with:

```
"react": "git+https://github.com/facebook/react.git#v17.0.1"
```

You can also use git+ssh if you have access to the repository via ssh key.

```
"react": "git+ssh://git@github.com/facebook/react.git#v17.0.1"
```

Then you can run `npm install` or yarn to install all the dependencies from Github.